# SCORM manifest: Selective tracking / completion?

Tags: scorm, scorm2004

In a SCORM organization, I have an item with 2 child items, accompanied by their respective resources. I want both items to be viewable, but only one of them shall be sufficient to mark the parent item as completed. (Not any one, but a certain one.) Can I achieve this by modifying the manifest alone or does the tracking backend have to implement something?

I tried two things in various combinations, but no success:

- Changed the resource's adlcp:scormType from "sco" to "asset".
- Played around with adlcp:completionThreshold in the organization and organization items.

The LMS (I used https://cloud.scorm.com/ for testing) doesn't seem to care and always returns the same results in the debug output and marks the course as incomplete/failed.

I am aware of ins:trackable, but unfortunately this is only available for SAVE1.0. Is there anything else I could do?

Also: From the documentation I'm not exactly sure how to use adlcp:completionThreshold properly. Is the parent or the child supposed to have this property? Do I need to propagate this property through the organization's hierarchy? Can someone give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use SCORM 2004, you can achieve selective score and completion tracking with the attributes of the `imsss:rollupRules` element. Rollup in SCORM speak refers to how the results are propagated upwards in the organization hierarchy.

I don't know the difference between satisfaction and completion of an object, so I always set `rollupObjectiveSatisfied` and `rollupProgressCompletion` to the same value, which works for my purposes. `objectiveMeasureWeight` determines how the score of each item is propagated upwards. It appears the weight is relative to other siblings, not to the total score of the parent item. That makes it easier to use by setting it to either 0.0 or 1.0, if you don't want to mess with the score.

Here's an example organization as it would appear in imsmanifest.xml:

```
<organizations default="org">
    <organization identifier="org">
        <title>Selective Tracking Demo</title>
        <item isvisible="true" identifier="parent">
            <title>Parent item</title>
            <item isvisible="true" identifier="item1" identifierref="item1_res">
                <title>No score, no completion</title>
                <imsss:sequencing>
                    <imsss:rollupRules objectiveMeasureWeight="0.0" rollupObjectiveSatisfied="false" rollupProgressCompletion="false"/>
                </imsss:sequencing>
            </item>
            <item isvisible="true" identifier="item2" identifierref="item2_res">
                <title>No score, but completion</title>
                <imsss:sequencing>
                    <imsss:rollupRules objectiveMeasureWeight="0.0" rollupObjectiveSatisfied="true" rollupProgressCompletion="true"/>
                </imsss:sequencing>
            </item>
            <item isvisible="true" identifier="item3" identifierref="item3_res">
                <title>Score and completion</title>
                <imsss:sequencing>
                    <imsss:rollupRules objectiveMeasureWeight="1.0" rollupObjectiveSatisfied="true" rollupProgressCompletion="true"/>
                </imsss:sequencing>
            </item>
        </item>
    </organization>
</organizations>
```

I haven't found any alternative for SCORM 1.2 and for SAVE 1.0 I keep using the `ins:trackable` and `adlcp:masteryscore` elements.

Answer (score 1):

### Completion and Success

Completion Threshold hooks into `cmi.progress_measure`. Like with the `cmi.score.scaled` values it uses a 0 to 1 decimal value to signify a percentage.  If your Completion Threshold is "0.8", the student needs to hit a progress measure of 0.8 (80%) to be `cmi.completion_status` of "completed", and would be "incomplete" for anything less. Also similar to `minNormalizedMeasure` contained within the imsmanifest which hooks into the `cmi.scaled_passing_score`.  This would aid in determining the `cmi.success_status` based on the `cmi.score.scaled` meeting or exceeding that threshold.  i.e. "passed" or "failed".

I have some deeper comments on this here: https://github.com/cybercussion/SCOBot/wiki/Instructional-Design-Planning

### Asset vs SCO

As far as I know using a scormType of "asset" is essentially a non-tracked item.  Like a PDF or Image.  These wouldn't communicate with the SCORM Runtime API.

Hope helps explain that a bit.

Comment: So this imsss:sequencing stuff gave me one more complex variable to play with, but again to no avail. The LMS seems to totally ignore any additional info I provide. It just sees an item with 4 sub-items and blindly assumes that all 4 must be completed (by its own internal measure) before the parent item is marked as completed. If only one sub-item is completed, the parent score is 25% and there seems to be nothing i can do about it. Neither our own nor the LMS's debug log show any activity regarding the parent score.

Comment: IMSS created the simple sequencing portion of the spec.  I believe even as I was consuming the standard I realized they had bolted on portions from other contributors.  These portions often were vague and quite often created a lot of ambiguity so you're not wrong to find yourself in a corner.  You've probably visited the scorm.com's golf examples https://scorm.com/wp-content/assets/golf_examples/Examples/SequencingPostTestRollup/SCORM%202004%203rd%20Edition/imsmanifest.xml where you can see they've setup some roll up functionality.

Comment: And also https://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/sequencing/sequencing-definition-model/ you may want to dig into how you can set rollup rules and actions to help meet your criteria.  I'll see if I can carve out some time to put a demo together since I don't have that exact requirement in my arsenal.

Comment: seems like this area may help - 
At Least Count
The action takes place if the number of children meeting the condition(s), exceeds a fixed number.
At Least Percent
The action takes place if the percentage of children meeting the condition(s), exceeds a value.

Comment: Yes, I've been through all of those until I finally hit something that actually solves my problem in a simple way. It's the attributes of the imsss:rollupRules element, found here: https://support.scorm.com/hc/en-us/articles/206169216-Courses-mark-failed-if-you-don-t-complete-the-quiz. First tests looked promising, but I wanted to get a working version together before I posted it as an answer. Will do so later today. Thanks for your help, Mark!